# How to setup multiple keys for components in template tag using v-for?

Tags: vue.js, key, vue-component, v-for

I wanted to render a list using v-for. It's simple enough, the documentation explains almost every use case. I want it to look like that:

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
      <CustomComponent :item="item"/>
      <Separator v-if="index !== items.length-1"/>
</template>
```

Unfortunately, the documentation does not say how to set a key for multiple custom components in one v-for.

Obviously, I don't want to include separator to my custom component, because it is used in other places too. Code I have pasted is generating those errors:
`'template' cannot be keyed. Place the key on real elements instead.`
I can set a key on component and separator using an index but I got errors: `Duplicate keys detected: 'x'. This may cause an update error.`

For now, I'm doing it like that but it's an ugly hack and would not work with more components in one template.

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in items">
      <CustomComponent :item="item" :key="(index+1)*-1"/>
      <Separator v-if="index !== items.length-1" :key="(index+1)"/>
</template>
```

Example from documentation explains templates on the list with basic components which does not require keys.
Does anyone know how should I do it correctly?

Ps. It is not recommended to use v-if on v-for. Could someone suggest how to change my code not to use v-if but don't render separator under the last element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was talking with a friend and he suggested the simplest and in my opinion the best solution. Just add a component prefix to every key e.g:

```
<template v-for="(item, index) in items">
      <CustomComponent :item="item" :key="'custom_component-'+index"/>
      <Separator v-if="index !== items.length-1" :key="'separator-'+index"/>
</template>
```

Comment: for Vue 3, key should be placed inside the `template` tag

Answer (score 2):

Here is how I was able to generate a key -- you could customize the generateKey method to return whatever you like.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div
      v-for="(item, index) in items"
      :key="generateKey(item, index)"
    >Item {{ index }} : {{ item }}</div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      items: ["Sun", "Moon", "Stars", "Sky"]
    };
  },
  methods: {
    generateKey(item, index) {
      const uniqueKey = `${item}-${index}`;
      return uniqueKey;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Working Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/30ojo1683p

Comment: I do not think that it's the same case. Because why should I generate a special key just for separator? A separator will not be updated ever, it fully depends on the item which is rendered above it.